# Keypress event of aspxMemo control

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

Hi..

I have added aspxMemo control in my webpage :

```
txtComments.ClientSideEvents.KeyPress = "function(s,e){e.processOnServer = false;}";
```

but user can type every word in the textbox.. `e.processOnServer = false` doesn't effect

how can i prevent user to write single word in the MEmo control ?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, try [Enabled](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxEdit_Enabledtopic) or [ReadOnly](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxEdit_ReadOnlytopic) ASPxMemo properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [ASPxClientTextEdit Methods](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsScriptsASPxClientTextEditClassMethodsTopic), may be these solve your problem.

I have restricted some level, but try to improve it more. the following example write the single character but clear the editor text.

```
     <dx:ASPxMemo ID="ASPxMemo1" ClientInstanceName ="aspxMemo" runat="server" Height="71px" Width="170px">
            <ClientSideEvents KeyUp="function(s, e) {
    //s.SetValue('');

s.SetText('');
}" />
```

Hope this help you to implement your functionality..

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding what `processonserver` does.

It causes the related event to fire **when a postback occurs**. If you never perform a postback then your server side code will never run.

See the [documentation here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxClassesScriptsASPxClientProcessingModeEventArgs_processOnServertopic).

If you want to control what the user can type into a Memo you should handle this at the client side as calling back to the server after each key press is not recommended unless you can guarantee extremely fast response times.